# How to limit size of result set in doctrine 2?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

If I'm using the `findBy` method of the repository class, how can I limit the size of the result set?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

In Doctrine 2.1 method `EntityRepository#findBy()` now accepts additional parameters for ordering, limit and offset.

[Documentation: Working with objects - Querying by simple conditions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

Example:

```
 public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
```

usage:

```
$myLimit = 30;
$myOffset = 20;

$product = $repository->findBy(
    array('name' => 'foo'),
    array('price' => 'ASC'),
    $myLimit,
    $myOffset
);
```

Comment: Thx for the reply, NikSen!  I haven't checked Doctrine's site lately so I didn't realize this!

Comment: Would be really helpful if the answer had actually listed examples of how the parameters are used.

Comment: Agreed, I've been searching around for the answer to this for a few minutes myself.

Comment: Will the limit be sql or an integer?

Answer (score 5):

For [Doctrine Query Language](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html#limiting-the-result) you have:

```
QueryBuilder::setMaxResults(integer $maxResults)
```

Answer (score 3):

The findBy() method of the generic repository class doesn't support this.

I would write your own repository (as [outlined here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories)) and override findBy() to take additional parameters.  Your new implementation could use the query builder, or plain-old-DQL to build up the proper query.  (I'd use the querybuilder, as you can probably just pass the $critera param right into [QueryBuilder::where()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.0/doctrine/orm/querybuilder.html#where%28%29))

Comment: Thx timdev, this is the suggestion I ended up using with Doctrine 2.0.